# How to select specific jetty version in Gretty plugin

Tags: gradle, jetty, gretty

I am using [Gretty](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/index.html) plugin for running web application from Gradle script. Is it possible to select a specific version of jetty container to run? Not just `jetty9` vs `jetty8`, but e.g. `9.2.13.v20150730`

Comment: i'm having the same question. have you figured it out?

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty/issues/330

Answer (score 5):

Since Gretty 2.0.0 it is possible to override versions of Jetty and `servlet-api` using gradle.properties file: http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Overriding-servlet-container-versions.html

For instance:

```
jetty9Version = 9.2.22.v20170606
```